# Open the same app after downloading an a update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i'm doing a application update, and i've already code the part thats download and extracts content.

now, i need to close current app, and open the same, but with the new .exe
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use this prop and inject it in **Ctor** `private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;`

```
//ToDo: inject it
private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;


//use this to restart application
_hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
```